# More like this for arrays

Tags: elasticsearch, morelikethis

Every document have an array with weights for each element. How I can get the most similar documents arrays. I think that function more_like_this making the same, but with texts.
Need realiztion in by tools of elasticsearch, of course.

["str":int,"str":int,...]